# What's wrong with this yaml file?

Tags: yaml, bukkit

I have a plugin.yml file for a bukkit plugin:

```
name: SlayCraft
version: 1.0.0
main: src.john01dav.slaycraft.SlayCraft

commands:
  scsetspawn:
    permission: slaycraft.setspawn
    description: Sets the SlayCraft spawn point to where you are standing
    usage: /scsetsapwn <arena/lobby>
  scjoin:
    permission: slaycraft.join
    description: Joins the SlayCraft game
    usage: /scjoin
  scfirework:
    permission: slaycraft.firework
    description: Launches a firework at the player's location
    usage: /scfirework
  scexplosion:
    permission: slaycraft.explosion:
    description: Launches an explosion at the player's location
    usage: /scexplosion

permissions:
  slaycraft.setspawn:
    default: op
  slaycraft.join:
    default: true
  slaycraft.firework:
    default: op
  slaycraft.explosion:
    default: op
```

This yaml looks perfectly fine to me, and yet [there are errors](http://tinyurl.com/le2fs5d). Any ideas? I have searched for people having similar errors, but none of them seem explicable.

Comment: `permission: slaycraft.explosion:` has an unneeded colon at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty specific:

```
ERROR:

mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 19, column 36:
        permission: slaycraft.explosion:
                                       ^
```

You have an extra colon on this line:

```
    permission: slaycraft.firework
    description: Launches a firework at the player's location
    usage: /scfirework
  scexplosion:
    permission: slaycraft.explosion: #<-- This colon is not needed.
    description: Launches an explosion at the player's location
    usage: /scexplosion
```

Remove it.